# Creating a schema relationship without common IDs

Tags: sql, database-design, ddl

I'm trying to create a database schema use different IDs in each table
i.e:

```
Table1: A_ID, A_FName, A_LName
Table2: B_ID, B_FName, B_LName
etc;
```

How can I link these in the relationship view, because I am recieving #1452 errors?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Returning this product specific error code 1452...)

Comment: Show us your DDL statements. (CREATE TABLE etc.)

Comment: What is this #1452 error? Please **[edit]** your question and add the full statement(s) that produces this error and the complete error message.

Comment: What is the relationship? Are you trying to join on ID? FName? LName? Some combination?